# Escaping +(plus) sign in Kendo grid ASP.NET MVC ClientTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I've having a problem defining a ASP.NET MVC ClientTemplate for a column in a Kendo grid because the '+' sign is being stripped out, which causes the client-side generated template to fail because of bad syntax.

My ClientTemplate is:

```
c.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#='Hello' + Name#")
```

In the client, however, this gets reduced to:

```
template: "#='Hello'   Name#"
```

i.e. the plus sign has been rendered as a space (similar to URL encoding I guess). The template works perfectly if I use from JS directly (see this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/eyovaz/2/edit)).

Does anyone know how I can escape the + sign so I can use it in the ClientTemplate?

I have tried escaping using '`\\+`' (gets rendered as '`\`'), '`\+`' (invalid C#), `&#43;` (same as `+`, although others such as `&#44;`' work fine).

Any ideas? Thanks.

For reference I'm using Razor markup and Q2 2012 Kendo release (can't use Q3 yet as limited by jQuery version as we're upgrading from Telerik)

**NOTE:** before anyone asks why I'm doing this, my ClientTemplate is actually more complex but this is a simplified example to illustrate the problem :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution (possibly more of a workaround). Rather than writing inline JavaScript I moved my code to a separate JS function and called that from the template code, e.g.:

```
#=myFunctionToDoComplicatedStuff(Name)#
```

To be honest, for reasons of testability, reuse and general good practice this is probably the approach that should be taken anyway. It's a bit annoying for something trivial though!

Answer (score 11):

I checked the source code<sup>1</sup>, the MVC wrapper is calling `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` on all templates before it renders them to JS.  So to escape your + sign (or any other reserved URL character), use [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  In this case `%2B`.

```
c.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#='Hello' %2B Name#")
```

<sup>1</sup> v2013.3, src\Kendo.Mvc\Kendo.Mvc\UI\Grid\Columns\GridColumnBase.cs, line 135.  I suspect this is a bug and they meant to call `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a simple solution for doing concatenation in your ClientTemplate that avoids the encoding issue with plus signs, you can use the javascript concat function like this:

```
c.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#='Hello'.concat(Name)#")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking the arithmetic and putting it outside the quotations as below:

`c.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#='Hello'" + "Name#")`

Comment: My actual code is more complex than a string concatenation - there's a bit of logic as part of a conditional statement that does actually need to do an arithmetic addition so I do need the +. Only workaround I've got so far is to move the JS out to a function and call it but would be nice to do it in the template to keep it all together. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I just ran into this and solved it by subtracting a negative value. Such as:

```
kendo.parseFloat(Amount)  - -kendo.parseFloat(Tip)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by using an [alternative plus sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2795/index.htm).

`c.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#='Hello' (<span style=\\'font-size: 0.6em\\'>&#10133;</span>{ Name#")`

This will result in...

```
template: "#='Hello + Name#"
```